# Python: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

I am doing a project which involves various functions within a class Linked_List which is a doubly-linked list and part of the code involves finding the number of nodes in the list. When I print this out however I get this:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-8ba59f440a47> in <module>()
 17 
 18 if __name__ == '__main__':
 19     x = Linked_List([1,2,3,4,5])
 20     print(x)
 21 

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**My code is below:**

```
 class Linked_List:
     class Node:
         def __init__(self, val, prev, next):
             self.val = val
             self.prev = prev
             self.next = next
     def __init__(self):
         self._header = self._Node(None, None, None)
         self._trailer = self._Node(None, None, None)
         self._header._next = self._trailer
         self._trailer._prev = self._header
         self._size = 0
     def __len__(self):
         return self._size
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     x = Linked_List([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
     print(x)
```

Comment: Do *not post images of code*. Post the code in the question itself as formatted text.

Comment: But yeah, you've defined your `LinkedList` `__init__` to take only `self`, but you are passing it a list. Also, why have you nested `Node` inside `LinkedList`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am not fluent in python, and I am taking a course in for data structures in python, and I took some of the code from the textbook for the course which has nested _Node in it but the instructor asked for it the first __init__ to be public and the next __init__ to be private and it makes no sense to me.

Comment: You should be confused. Python doesn't have access modifiers, so there are no "public" and "private" attributes. 10 bucks says your professor hasn't changed their lesson plans when they switched from Java to Python as the teaching language.

Answer (score 0):

What happened is simple you defined the `__init__` in linked list as:

```
 def __init__(self):
```

Which takes one positional argument namely `self` but passed in an additional parameter - a list.

Comment: So what could I do to fix it?

Comment: Look at how LinkedList is typically implemented in Python. Even if you've fixed that there's a lot of other things you should fix as well.